# OpenMP threadprivate variable template

Tags: openmp, c++14, variable-templates

I want a variable template to be `threadprivate` as well. Could this be done ? Something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct Tpl { };

template<typename X>
extern Tpl<X> var;
#pragma omp threadprivate(var) // <<< No compiler supports this.
template<typename X>
Tpl<X> var;
```

Comment: If there is no better solution, you may try to give the variable the C++11 `thread_local` specifier. AFAIK it is not guaranteed to be compatible with OpenMP, but often is.

Comment: I'm currently using a tricky hack: wrap all access to `var` with a class template `template<class X> Access`, then specialize all possible `X` for class `Access` in my program, and in the specialized methods, access different non-template `threadprivate` variables like `var_int`, `var_double`, etc. It works, but boring to implement.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you need a templated variable here? Surely your worker function will only access a small predetermined number of its incarnations (as your "tricky hack" seems to confirm).

Comment: Please note that this concept is called *[variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template)*, there is no such thing as a *template variable* in C++.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks for the info & edit.

Comment: @TheVee The actual code is much more complicated. In the actual code, the variable template is a special memory allocator that isn't thread-safe.